# Difference between "está" and "esta" or "esté" and "este"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, cópulas, diacríticos, deixis

How do I know if I have to use the one with accent and not the one without accent? Could you provide examples?

Comment: And don't forget *ésta* and *éste*! :)

Comment: I've never heard of "ésta" and "éste". Also is grammatically incorrect because is a grave word.

Comment: @AlfredoO no, it's not grammatically incorrect to say ésta/éste. http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anfibolog%C3%ADa

Comment: @AlfredoO: I believe the accent on the first *e* used to be required for demonstrative pronouns when the *e* was lowercase, but it sounds like RAE changed that so it's only necessary in case of ambiguity. Maybe that's worth another question though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a matter of stress. If the stressed syllable is the first one, you don't write the accent. If it's the last one, you do.
You know, the rule states that "if the stress is in the last syllable and it ends in vowel, n or s, you must write the accent".

Besides, `está` and `esté` are forms of the verb *`estar`*, whereas `esta` and `este` are demonstratives or pronouns.

Some examples:

> - Esta mesa está aquí.
> - Es mejor que este jarrón esté aquí.

Comment: Specially the answer to the question is on the sentence that starts with *Besides,...*

Answer (score 1):

"está" is the 3rd. person, singular of the verb "estar". In English: "is".

"esta" is a pronoun, it translates to "this".

Esta casa está inclinada.
Esta linea está torcida.
Esta mañana está muy bonita.