# All is Well - Todo esta bien

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Which is correct?

English   - **All is Well**

Espanol   - **Todo es bien / Todo está bien**

I am confused with es and está. still I don't get a clear view.

I referred [this](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1828/difference-between-esta-and-esta-or-este-and-este) too.

Please help to understand. Thanks!

Comment: use `está` when it is a temporary states, and `es` for durable or permanent states

Comment: related http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/what-is-the-correct-verb-for-temporary-transient-color

Comment: I don't think you would ever see 'ser' with 'bien.'  But there might be an exception.

Comment: In a general sense, it is common to say **Todo va bien** (**All goes well**).

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is "Todo está bien." I don't remember the rule right, but I usually use "es" when i refer to a particular characteristic of the subject: The car is red (El carro es rojo), The car is big (El carro es grande).  In the case of "está", I use it more to refer to a particular state or status of the subject: The car is wet (El carro está mojado), The car is far (El carro está lejos). I need to go back and review the official rule, it's been a while, but in general terms, I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: use `está` when it is a temporary states, and `es` for durable or permanent states

Answer (score 0):

All is Well also can traslate to "Todo correcto".

The traslation of To be in Spanish can be the verb "ser" or "estar" depending the context.

The verb "Ser" refers to a person or a object and the verb "estar" refers to the state of things or persons.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that is "bien" (the situation, the wind blowing your ship) at the time can also become "mal", right? Since that "bien" is mutable, you must use "esta".